Can I use "I'm on the clock" if I'm self-employed?
As I've checked from some sources, "on the clock" means "working" but some also added "getting paid for the amount of time they work."
But I'm running my own business and no one hires me. Besides, I'm working on R&D so that I can provide better products for my customers, not that they ask me to work or something. Can I use "I'm on the clock" in this situation?

Another bad dv.

Yes, self-employed people get paid too. If your contract with a client specifies that you get paid more for working longer then you are "on the clock".
For example, I might hire a gardener and agree to pay them 25 pounds per hour to work in my garden this weekend, that gardener is "on the clock". Or I might hire a gardener to repair my fence (and they'll get paid the same no matter how long it takes them) that gardener is not on the clock.
If you earn money from selling products, you get more money by selling more products (or selling better products) not for working longer.  In which case, you are not "on the clock".

I'm running my own business and no one hires me. Besides, I'm working on R&D so that I can provide better products for my customers, not that they ask me to work or something. Can I use "I'm on the clock" in this situation?

could you give me an answer to this?

If nobody hires you,  where do you get money from?  If you are selling products, do you get more money if you work for longer hours?  Or do you get more money if you develop more products?  If the later, then you are not "on the clock".

"on the clock" depends on context.
You can be your own timekeeper.
It just means the passing time has a monetary value associated with it.
If you have three hours to do a job, and it 2 hours and 45 minutes into it, and your kids start bugging you, you could say it.
